# AM radio sound frequency

Tags: amplitude-modulation

I have a radio transmitter and a radio receiver .

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f84Wyl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will the sound produced by the loudspeaker have the same frequency with the tuning frequency?

Comment: While the L3/C2 combo would be a sensible model of an antenna (you might want to annotate that!), simply turning on and off 1 V DC wouldn't make a transmitter. You're indeed missing the part that generates any frequency!

Comment: You have no tuning capacitor on the "transmitter".

Comment: And neither of this is an "FM" radio. You're nowhere modulating a frequency! So, titling this "FM" is wrong, and I'm not quite sure where to start explaining how radio works with this.

Comment: Is your title correct? Are you really making an **FM** radio? I don't see how you are generating the carrier, so it looks more like **AM** to me.

Comment: You have neither.... start again.

Comment: Yes maybe I am new to telecommunications . By turning on/off the switch at a steady rate  I will induce 2 opposite currents in the radio receiver creating a square wave form signal ( due to the diode).

Comment: The L3/C2 is the tuner.

Comment: Your "tuner" can't oscillate because there's a diode in the circuit. The idea with a tuned receiver is that it is tuned to the transmitter - but your transmitter has no tuning. You really need to read a lot. Make an AM receiver that will pick up a commercial station first. Then look into making a receiver. There is much to learn.

Comment: A really well designed crystal radio has just enough power for a crystal earpiece. You haven't a hope of driving a loudspeaker without an amplifier.

Comment: Yes you are right I just realize...